# Displaying an image when ScrollPane item is highlighted

Tags: java, libgdx, gui

I would like to have images displayed when an item in the list is highlighted as a form of a "preview" of the map that is selected. I'm not sure how i would implement this with clickListeners or things of that sort as I am new to libgdx and would like some assistance in making this happen. For example the transition between the images following:
[image: Plain Level Select Menu with nothing selected]
[image: Having selected a level to play with respective preview]

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

public class LevelSelect implements Screen {

private Stage stage;
private Table table;
private Label heading;
private BitmapFont white, black;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private Skin skin;
private List<String> list;
private ScrollPane scrollPane;
private TextButton play, back;
private String[] items = new String[] { "UNDECIDED", "\"East Side!!! West Side!!!\"" };

@Override
public void show() {    

    stage = new Stage();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack");
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), atlas);

    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    list = new List<String>(skin);
    list.setItems(items);

    white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/fd.fnt"), false);
    black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/fd2.fnt"), false);
    LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(black, Color.WHITE);
    heading = new Label("Level Select", headingStyle);
    heading.setFontScale(3);

    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(list, skin);

    play = new TextButton("PLAY", skin);
    back = new TextButton("BACK", skin);
    back.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
        {
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
        }
    });

    //TEXTURES FOR MAP PREVIEW
    Texture kingdoms_0 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image/mapPreview/kingdoms_0"));
    Image kingdoms_0_pic = new Image(kingdoms_0);
    Texture kingdoms_1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image/mapPreview/kingdoms_1"));
    Image kingdoms_1_pic = new Image(kingdoms_1);

    table.add(heading).center().colspan(3).row();
    table.add(scrollPane).expandY().left();
    table.add(kingdoms_0_pic).row();
    table.add(play);
    table.add(back);

    stage.addActor(table);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
    table.setFillParent(true);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
}

}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!